# Index Maintenance on Indexed View using Ola Hallengren Script

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, ola-hallengren, index-maintenance

I’m using Ola Hallengren's below script in my environment and it fails with the error:

```
USE DBA
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
    @Databases = ‘USER_DATABASES’,
    @FragmentationLow = NULL,
    @FragmentationMedium = ‘INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE’,
    @FragmentationHigh = ‘INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE’,
    @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
    @FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
    @UpdateStatistics = ‘ALL’,
    @PageCountLevel = 0 ,
    @LogToTable = ‘N’
```

> Msg 50000, Sev 16, State 1, Line 153 : Msg 2706, Table ‘_abcd’ does not exist. [SQLSTATE 42000]

‘_abcd’ actually is a view and the stored procedure is unable to update statistics on view and it fails.
we've indexes on this view
Please guide me how can I solve this issue

Comment: See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1b8608ab-5345-4f14-a6b2-8a02b468aa23/strange-problem-with-statistics-on-view?forum=sqldatabaseengine) one.

Comment: Which user rights does the user, you are executing olla's scripts with, have? Try executing this: UPDATE STATISTICS [Test].[dbo].[_abcd] [Name of the index]

Comment: Can you try and run SQL Server Profiler to find out what is the exact query that generates this issue ? Can you also give us the definition of the _abcd view ?

Answer (score 1):

I run Ola's scripts from SQL Agent, and the jobs that use them are owned by an ID that has sysadmin server role.  You could also ask Ola for his thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

Havent really tried to debug the script, but i can see just from the parameters what it essentially does.
There are many scripts online that you can use to do just that
The one that i use pretty often is this:

```
DECLARE @MaxFragmentation TINYINT=30
,@MinimumPages SMALLINT=1000
,@SQL nvarchar(max)
,@ObjectName NVARCHAR(300)
,@IndexName NVARCHAR(300)
,@CurrentFragmentation DECIMAL(9, 6)
DECLARE @FragmentationState TABLE
(
SchemaName SYSNAME
,TableName SYSNAME
,object_id INT
,IndexName SYSNAME
,index_id INT
,page_count BIGINT
,avg_fragmentation_in_percent FLOAT
,avg_page_space_used_in_percent FLOAT
,type_desc VARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO @FragmentationState
SELECT
s.name as SchemaName
,t.name as TableName
,t.object_id
,i.name as IndexName
,i.index_id
,x.page_count
,x.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
,x.avg_page_space_used_in_percent
,i.type_desc
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SAMPLED') x
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON x.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON x.object_id = i.object_id AND x.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE x.index_id > 0 AND i.type_desc <> 'NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE' and i.type <4
AND alloc_unit_type_desc = 'IN_ROW_DATA'
DECLARE INDEX_CURSE CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT QUOTENAME(x.SchemaName)+'.'+QUOTENAME(x.TableName)
,CASE WHEN x.type_desc = 'CLUSTERED' THEN 'ALL'
ELSE QUOTENAME(x.IndexName) END
,x.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM @FragmentationState as x
LEFT OUTER JOIN @FragmentationState y ON x.object_id = y.object_id AND y.index_id = 1
WHERE (
x.type_desc = 'CLUSTERED'
AND y.type_desc = 'CLUSTERED'
)
OR y.index_id IS NULL
ORDER BY x.object_id
,x.index_id
OPEN INDEX_CURSE
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
FETCH NEXT FROM INDEX_CURSE INTO @ObjectName, @IndexName
,@CurrentFragmentation
IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
BREAK
SELECT @SQL='ALTER INDEX '
+@IndexName+' ON '+@ObjectName
+CASE WHEN @CurrentFragmentation <= 30
THEN ' REORGANIZE;'
ELSE ' REBUILD'
+CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')) LIKE 'Data Center%'
OR CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')) LIKE 'Enterprise%'
OR CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')) LIKE 'Developer%'
THEN ' WITH (ONLINE=ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB=ON) '
END+';'
END
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL
END
CLOSE INDEX_CURSE
DEALLOCATE INDEX_CURSE
```

Based on your parameters it will defragment the indexes, either rebuilding or reorganizing depending on @MaxFragmentation. Online or Offline ,depending on edition. 
Hope it helps